# SubSonic 3 simple repository question

Tags: c#, asp.net, orm, subsonic3, subsonic-simplerepository

I am using simple repository pattern of Subsonic 3 to store and get values from database. I want to know if I should use Singleton patten to create `SimpleRepository` or should create one whenever is needed. Like if I have Person class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public void Save()
    {
        var repo=new SimpleRepository("constr"); //CREATE REPO HERE
        repo.Add<Person>(this);
    }

    public void Load(int id)
    {
        var repo=new SimpleRepository("constr");//CREATE REPO HER
        .....
    }
}
```

Or access repo like this

```
public class Person
{
    public void Save()
    {
        var repo=RepoHelper.GetRepository();//GET FROM SINGLETON OBJECT
        repo.Add<Person>(this);
    }

    public void Load(int id)
    {
        var repo=RepoHelper.GetRepository();
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a singleton class for it. It seems to be the right thing when you have a centralized data store. I allows you to manage the type of repository in one place. Is also has the advantage that it makes it easier to switch from reposition type.

```
public static class Repository
{
    static SimpleRepository repo;

    public static IRepository GetRepository()
    {
        if (repo == null)
        {
            lock (repo)
            {
                repo = new SimpleRepository("NamedConnectionString",
                    SimpleRepositoryOptions.RunMigrations);
            }
        }

        return repo;
    }
}
```

Ps. I also build a base record class to do a Save() and to manage foreign relations.

Comment: I will also try your base record class approach in my next project.

Comment: In few days I'll write up a blog with the base class that I'm using. I'll keep you posted.